# Unable to load ViewController from tableview RowSelected in xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin, tableview

On selected tableview rowselected loading a DetailViewcontroller class.

```
    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            if (OnRowSelected != null) {
                OnRowSelected (this, new RowSelectedEventArgs (tableView, indexPath));
            }

                var detailController = new DetailViewController ();
                    UINavigationController controller = new UINavigationController();
                    controller.PushViewController(detailController, true);
}
```

Unable to load the DetailViewController.

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
```

method is in `UITableViewSource`

Is there any way to load DetailViewController on  rowSelected.

Comment: Why do you create new instances of your `UINavigationController`?

Comment: @Larme DetailViewController detailViewController = new DetailViewController();
   NavigationController.PushViewController (detailViewController, true);  it shows an error.. NavigationController does not exist in the currect context.  So i Created the UINavigationController Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your table, you need to place it within the context of a Navigation controller.

UINavigationController nav = new UINavigationController(myTableViewController);

Then, when you want to display your DetailViewController, you can push it onto the already existing Navigation controller.  However, by default your TableSource does not have access to NavigationController - you will need to pass a reference to your TableView controller when you create the TableSource so that the TableSource can access the NavigationController:

```
// in your controller, when you assign the source
this.TableView.Source = new MyTableViewSource(this);

// in your source, keep a class level ref to the parent
MyTableViewController _parent;

// your Source's constructor
public MyTableViewSource(MyTableViewController parent) {
  _parent = parent;
}

// finally, in your RowSelected use the _parent reference to access the Nav controller
var detailController = new DetailViewController ();
_parent.NavigationController.PushViewController(detailController, true);
```